# Possible to instantiate object given its type in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been programming in Java way too long, and finding my way back to some C++.  I want to write some code that given a class (either a type_info, or its name in a string) can create an instance of that class.  For simplicity, let's assume it only needs to call the default constructor.  Is this even possible in C++, and if not is it coming in a future TR?

I have found a way to do this, but I'm hoping there is something more "dynamic".  For the classes I expect to wish to instantiate (this is a problem in itself, as I want to leave that decision up to configuration), I have created a singleton factory with a statically-created instance that registers itself with another class.  eg. for the class Foo, there is also a FooFactory that has a static FooFactory instance, so that at program startup the FooFactory constructor gets called, which registers itself with another class.  Then, when I wish to create a Foo at runtime, I find the FooFactory and call it to create the Foo instance.  Is there anything better for doing this in C++?  I'm guessing I've just been spoiled by rich reflection in Java/C#.

For context, I'm trying to apply some of the IOC container concepts I've become so used to in the Java world to C++, and hoping I can make it as dynamic as possible, without needing to add a Factory class for every other class in my application.

Comment: As a followup, is it possible to pass a "type" in C++?  ie. pass not a Foo object, but the Foo class, as a parameter to a function?  The Java equivalent that I'm thinking of is a method that takes a Class parameter, and you can pass in Foo.class

Answer (score 0):

You could always use templates, though I'm not sure that this is what your looking for:

```
template <typename T>
T
instantiate ()
{
  return T ();
}
```

Or on a class:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks Joe.  Yes, using templates could be a way to trim the lines of code required to implement the factory, however I'm hoping to find a way to avoid writing a factory per class to be dynamically created.  I suspect I won't though.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in C++ :)

You are correct that you will need a `Factory` to create those objects, however you might not need one `Factory` per file.

The typical way of going at it is having all instanciable classes derive from a common base class, that we will call `Base`, so that you'll need a single `Factory` which will serve a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` to you each time.

There are 2 ways to implement the `Factory`:

- You can use the `Prototype` pattern, and register an instance of the class to create, on which a `clone` function will be called.
- You can register a pointer to function or a functor (or `std::function<Base*()>` in C++0x)

Of course the difficulty is to register those entries dynamically. This is typically done at start-up during static initialization.

```
// OO-way
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  virtual Derived* clone() const { return new Derived(*this); }
private:
};

// start-up...
namespace { Base* derived = GetFactory().register("Derived", new Derived); }

// ...or in main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  GetFactory().register("Derived", new Derived(argv[1]));
}

// Pointer to function
class Derived: public Base {};

// C++03
namespace {
  Base* makeDerived() { return new Derived; }
  Base* derived = GetFactory().register("Derived", makeDerived);
}

// C++0x
namespace {
  Base* derived = GetFactory().register("Derived", []() { return new Derived; });
}
```

The main advantage of the start-up way is that you can perfectly define your `Derived` class in its own file, tuck the registration there, and no other file is impacted by your changes. This is great for handling dependencies.

On the other hand, if the prototype you wish to create requires some external information / parameters, then you are forced to use an initialization method, the simplest of which being to register your instance in `main` (or equivalent) once you have the necessary parameters.

*Quick note: the pointer to function method is the most economic (in memory) and the fastest (in execution), but the syntax is weird...*

Regarding the follow-up questions.

Yes it is possible to pass a type to a function, though perhaps not directly:

- if the type in question is known at compile time, you can use the templates, though you'll need some time to get acquainted with the syntax
- if not, then you'll need to pass some kind of ID and use the factory approach

If you need to pass something akin to `object.class` then it seems to me that you are approaching the double dispatch use case and it would be worth looking at the `Visitor` pattern.

Answer (score -1):

No. There is no way to get from a type's name to the actual type; rich reflection is pretty cool, but there's almost always a better way.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that trying to wholesale fit the Java way of doing IOC on to C++ is my first mistake.  Still, being able to dynamically wire up classes in config a la Spring is very powerful.  My Factory approach fulfills this desire, just not as cleanly as I'd like.

Comment: BTW, who gave the -1 here, and why... I'm interested in why you disagree with Jonathan.

Answer (score -1):

no such thing as "var" or "dynamic" in C++ last time I've checked(although that was a WHILE ago). You could use a (void*) pointer and then try casting accordingly. Also, if memory serves me right, C++ does have RTTI which is not reflection but can help with identifying types at runtime.

Comment: C++0x's `auto` is pretty much what C#'s `var` is. And both have absolutely nothing to do with dynamic typing.